WebSocket connection error with Laravel Reverb on Ubuntu server with aaPanel and Nginx
I'm setting up Laravel Reverb on an Ubuntu server that uses aaPanel and Nginx, but I am encountering an issue with WebSocket connections. The connection fails with the following error in the console:
app-D7hz6kql.js:17 WebSocket connection to 'wss://localhost:8080/app/tmfatfkesf8xdt5rdt7u?protocol=7&client=js&version=8.4.0-rc2&flash=false' failed
Here are my configurations
.env

BROADCAST_DRIVER=reverb
REVERB_APP_ID=633101
REVERB_APP_KEY=tmfatfkesf8xdt5rdt7u
REVERB_APP_SECRET=secret_key
REVERB_HOST=example_host.com
REVERB_PORT=8080
REVERB_SCHEME=https

VITE_REVERB_APP_KEY=tmfatfkesf8xdt5rdt7u
VITE_REVERB_HOST=example_host.com
VITE_REVERB_PORT=8080
VITE_REVERB_SCHEME=https

REVERB_TLS_CERT_PATH= /pathtocert/certificate.crt
REVERB_TLS_KEY_PATH= /pathtopkey/private.key

broadcasting.php

'reverb' => [
    'driver' => 'reverb',
    'key' => env('REVERB_APP_KEY'),
    'secret' => env('REVERB_APP_SECRET'),
    'app_id' => env('REVERB_APP_ID'),
    'options' => [
        'host' => env('REVERB_HOST'),
        'port' => env('REVERB_PORT', 443),
        'scheme' => env('REVERB_SCHEME', 'https'),
        'useTLS' => env('REVERB_SCHEME', 'https') === 'https',
    ],
    'client_options' => [],
],

reverb.php:
'reverb' => [
    'host' => env('REVERB_SERVER_HOST', '0.0.0.0'),
    'port' => env('REVERB_SERVER_PORT', 8080),
    'hostname' => env('REVERB_HOST'),
    'options' => [
        'tls' => [
            "local_cert"=> env("REVERB_TLS_CERT_PATH"),
            "local_pk"=> env("REVERB_TLS_KEY_PATH"),
        ],
    ],
    'max_request_size' => env('REVERB_MAX_REQUEST_SIZE', 10_000),
    'scaling' => [
        'enabled' => env('REVERB_SCALING_ENABLED', false),
        'channel' => env('REVERB_SCALING_CHANNEL', 'reverb'),
        'server' => [
            'url' => env('REDIS_URL'),
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', '6379'),
            'username' => env('REDIS_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD'),
            'database' => env('REDIS_DB', '0'),
        ],
    ],
    'pulse_ingest_interval' => env('REVERB_PULSE_INGEST_INTERVAL', 15),
    'telescope_ingest_interval' => env('REVERB_TELESCOPE_INGEST_INTERVAL', 15),
],

Nginx SSL Configuration:

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name supervisor.insourceerp.com;
    ssl_certificate /path/to/certificate.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/privatekey.pem;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_ciphers EECDH+CHACHA20:EECDH+AES128;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000";
    # Additional SSL and proxy settings

    location ~ /app/(?<reverbkey>.*) {  
        proxy_pass https://localhost:8080/app/$reverbkey;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location ~ ^/apps/(?<reverbid>[^/]+)/events$ {  
        proxy_pass https://localhost:8080/apps/$reverbid/events;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}



SSL has been verified using SSL Labs.
I’ve ensured that the WebSocket URL in the console matches the expected route (wss://localhost:8080).
The server's firewall settings are checked, and port 8080 is open.
Despite these configurations, the WebSocket connection still fails. Are there any additional steps or configurations needed to resolve this issue with Reverb on Nginx and aaPanel? Should I adjust the WebSocket URL or SSL settings? Any guidance would be appreciated.

Update, I connected to my socket only using ws though, all I had to do was run npm run build after modifying the .env.
Still can't connect using wss though
